# Geometric Series-Bounce Height of a Ball

Tags: geometric-series

A ball is dropped from a height of $20 \, \mathrm{m}$. It rebounds to a height of $16 \, \mathrm{m}$ and continues to rebound to eight-tenths of its previous height for subsequent bounces.

Calculate the total distance the ball travels before it comes to rest.

How do you answer this question?

I'm using the formula
$$
S_n = \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}, \qquad   r\lt 1
$$
I believe that the variables:
$$
\begin{align}
a &= 20 \\
r &= 0.8 \\
n &= \text{undefined}
\end{align}
$$
The answer is meant to equal $100 \, \mathrm{m}$ so, $S_n = 100 \, \mathrm{m}$.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The distance of the return journey after each bounce should be counted as well.

Comment: @hypergeometric: Indeed : I'd say the ball drops $100\mathrm{m}$ but travels $180\mathrm{m}$

Comment: The answer cannot be "meant" to be $100$. It is probably a typo: it should be $180$.

Answer (score 3):

You need the sum of the infinite geometric series given by
$$S=20+\frac{8}{10}\times20+\left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^2\times20+\cdots$$

For a geometric series
$$S=a+ar+ar^2+\cdots$$
The $N^{th}$ partial sum is given by
$$S_N=a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^{N-1}=\frac{a(1-r^N)}{1-r}$$

Then,
$$S=\lim_{N\to\infty}S_N=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{a(1-r^N)}{1-r}$$

If $|r|<1$, the limit exists and is given by,
$$S=\frac{a}{1-r}$$
Hence, here
$$S=\frac{20}{1-\frac{8}{10}}=100$$

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be $180$, as in $20 + 16 + 16 + 12.8 + 12.8 + 10.24 +10.24 \cdots$? The ball has to go up before it goes down again. $100\mathrm{m}$ would be the total distance the ball drops, $180\mathrm{m}$ the total distance the ball travels.

Comment: @EricDuminil: Indeed, you are right. The persons who upvoted this answer probably didn't bother to read it carefully (and critically).

Comment: @GoodDeeds, you have forgotten that the ball must also bounce back before coming back down again. Maybe delete this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that at iteration $n$ the ball goes down $d_n$ meters, and then goes up $u_n$ meters, for all $n \ge 0$. We are told that $d_0 = 20$ and that $u_n = \frac 8 {10} d_n = \frac 4 5 d_n$. It is also clear that $d_{n+1} = u_n$ for all $n \ge 0$. The total distance is

$$(d_0 + u_0) + (d_1 + u_1) + \dots = \sum _{n \ge 0} \left( d_n + \frac 4 5 d_n \right) = \frac 9 5 \sum _{n \ge 0} d_n \ .$$

Now, using the relations from the first paragraph, $d_{n+1} = u_n = \frac 4 5 d_n$, whence we get that $d_{n+1} = \left( \frac 4 5 \right) ^{n+1} d_0$ for all $n \ge 0$, whence it is immediate that $d_n = \left( \frac 4 5 \right) ^n d_0$ for all $n \ge 0$. Using this back in our sum, the total distance becomes

$$\frac 9 5 \sum _{n \ge 0} \left( \frac 4 5 \right) ^n d_0 = \frac 9 5 \frac 1 {1 - \frac 4 5} d_0 = 180 \ .$$